# xorshift128+ PRNG implementation in java w/o unsigned long

Tags: java, prng

Using this C code for reference (sourced from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift):

```
uint64_t s[2];
uint64_t xorshift128plus(void) {
    uint64_t x = s[0];
    uint64_t const y = s[1];
    s[0] = y;
    x ^= x << 23; // a
    x ^= x >> 17; // b
    x ^= y ^ (y >> 26); // c
    s[1] = x;
    return x + y;
}
```

Is the following the equivalent java code in terms of maintaining the randomness properties (other than a different mapping between seeds and return value):

```
long s[2];
long xorshift128plus(){
    long x = s[0];
    long y = s[1];
    s[0] = y;
    x ^= x << 23; // a
    x ^= x >>> 17; // b
    x ^= y ^ (y >>> 26); // c
    s[1] = x;
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: It actually looks *exactly* the same to me. What's the difference? Ignore the signedness of the results, obviously.

Comment: I just wanted confirmation that they are essentially equivalent.

Comment: The mapping between seeds an return values is the same too.

Comment: Looks the same to me. My implementation is logically identical to yours but to make bytecode shorter my implementation uses 2 longs instead of an array of long and joins lines for "b" and "c" into one.

Answer (score 1):

I distribute a complete implementation of PRNGs from the xorshift family in the DSI utilities: http://dsiutils.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/util/package-summary.html